OpenSSL: Create CAfile
I have a X.509 certificate mycert.pem and a private-key mykey.pem for it.
Furthermore the certificate has a root-certificate and a intermediate-certificate to build a complete chain.
I had to add both the root-cert root.pem and the interm-cert interm.pem to /etc/ssl/certs with the correkt hash-link to make openssl verify the certificate OK.
mycert.pem: OK

Now I try to use openssl s_client.
I get an error at the server-side because I have set -key and also -cert but not -CAfile.
openssl s_client -connect my.host.org:433 -cert mycert.pem -key mykey.pem

I am not sure about that. How can I create the file for -CAfile?
I tried to set -CApath /etc/ssl/certs instead of -CAfile, but did not help.

you should try to use the update-ca-trust utility it will read the content of /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted and add the new Root CA & intermediate CA to /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/openssl/ca-bundle.trust.crt.

I do not have that binary or that paths. My certs are in /etc/ssl/certs.

on CentOS it in ca-certificates package

Is your server sending the cert chain or just the leaf cert? Use the -showcerts option to see. If just the leaf cert is sent then it won't connect the cert that is sent to the root CA in /etc/ssl/certs because the intermediate isn't a root and isn't trusted.
